# Material design input field not changing after fetching the value from database (firebase)

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase

I have a web page that contains 3 fields. The web page uses Firebase Real-time DB to save the data.

After updating the data, when I fetch the data, the material input field won't push the label on top but instead overlaps the value (as shown in the screenshot)

Following are the code that I am using,
HTML -

```
<div class="md-form">
   <input type="number" id="v1" value="" class="form-control">
   <label for="v1">Value 1</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <input type="number" id="v2" value="" class="form-control">
    <label for="v2">Value 2</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <input type="number" id="v3" class="form-control">
    <label for="v3">Value 3</label>
</div>
```

JS -

```
rootRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    $('#v1').val(snapshot.child('v1').val());
    $('#v2').val(snapshot.child('v2').val());
    $('#v3').val(snapshot.child('v3').val());
})
```

Output screenshot after fetching the data -
[Values overlapping the label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EgZG.png)

Any inputs to fix this issue will be very valuable.

Comment: What material library are you using? I am pretty sure you are not designing form according to library's instruction.

Comment: The issue is only when I try to set the values not when I try to enter the values. When I try to enter the values, the floating label jumps to the top and everything seems to be fine but when I try to set the values on the load of the DOM, the labels seem to not recognize it but when I click the field, it recognize it and moves to top.

Comment: Sure, could you tell ne nom package or library name you are using? May be your approach to set value is wrong.

Comment: I have just imported these two CDNs -  ```<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.19.1/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">```

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On library's sample page for input I am seeing same issue as well when setting value from `JavaScript` and there are already reported [BUG](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/jquery/input-value-problem/) [BUG](https://mdbootstrap.com/support/jquery/set-value-to-input-programatically/) for the issue, may be you want to follow up on that. [image]

As mentioned in the bug, you can fix issue by adding class `active` to associated label after setting value from javascript.

```
$("label[for='v1']").addClass('active');
$("label[for='v2']").addClass('active');
$("label[for='v3']").addClass('active');
```

Comment: This actually works. Thank you, Dipen for helping me to fix this! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if it works

```
input               {
      font-size:18px;
      padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
      display:block;
      width:300px;
      border:none;
      border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
    }
    
    /* LABEL ======================================= */
    label                {
      color:#999; 
      font-size:18px;
      font-weight:normal;
      position:absolute;
      pointer-events:none;
      left:5px;
      top:10px;
      transition:0.2s ease all; 
      -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
      -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
    }
    
    /* active state */
    input:focus ~ label, input:valid ~ label        {
      top:-20px;
      font-size:14px;
      color:#5264AE;
    }
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work as the label is not working only when I try to set the field values from the DB